# ImageView in ConstraintsLayout doesn`t work when MainActivity extends FragmentActivity?

Tags: android

ImageView in ConstraintsLayout doewn`t show picture when MainActvity extends FragmentActivity
this is a simple example what happend

this is MainActivity.XMl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.xiaojian.constraintslayouttest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

then MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity,the picture can display normally,

but if MainActivity extends FragmentActivity,the picture can not display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` instead of `app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

**app:srcCompat**

> Using AppCompat and app:srcCompat is the most foolproof method of integrating vector drawables into your app.

**android:src**

> Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.

Check [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) blog post.

For vector drawables use AppCompat with `app:srcCompat` and for others use `android:src`

Comment: but it doesn`t work for my actually question ,its my mistake to description my question.

Comment: the problem is that not MainActivity but HomeFragment extends Fragment,like this :
**public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener**
  then I change app:srcCompat to android:src,it still doesn`t work

Comment: Yes,seems like ImageView in ConstraintsLayout doesn`t work in Fragment